# Package Manager Console issues

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, nuget

I installed Asp.net MVC 3 beta which also installs NuPack, but when I open a project in Visual Studio 2010 Express, the Package Manager Console gives me this error message:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.InitialSessionState' from assembly 'System.Management.Automation, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.
   at NuPackConsole.Host.PowerShell.Implementation.PowerShellHostProvider.CreateHost(IConsole console)
   at NuPackConsole.Implementation.PowerConsole.HostInfo.get_WpfConsole()
   at NuPackConsole.Implementation.PowerConsoleToolWindow.get_WpfConsole()System.InvalidOperationException: Can't start ConsoleDispatcher. Host is null.
   at NuPackConsole.Implementation.Console.ConsoleDispatcher.Start()
   at NuPackConsole.Implementation.PowerConsoleToolWindow.MoveFocus(FrameworkElement consolePane)
```

I have been able to download packages via the "Add Package Reference" menu option, but not with the Package Manager Console. Please what could the problem be? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Download the [Windows Management Framework Core package](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/968930) which contains PowerShell 2.

Use the one that matches your version of Windows.

I got exactly the same, and as the stack explicitly mentions PowerShell I searched / downloaded / installed (& unfortunately were asked to restart) ... done :)

Comment: Thanks eglasius and Darin. I've got it up and running now :)

Answer (score 2):

NuPack Console requires PowerShell 2.0, so make sure that you have it installed. If you are running this on Windows XP, this might not be the case.